# What motherboard has BIOS that allows for better customization of BOOT priorities?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, motherboard, bios

I have a GIGABYTE GA-H170M-D3H DDR3 motherboard. The way this motherboard handles my boot priorities is a serious pain.

I have a harddrive with windows 10 and another one with Ubuntu. Whenever I decide to boot from the Ubuntu harddrive, it makes it so my computer always starts with the ubuntu drive. I've tried going into the BIOS to change this, but it doesn't give me the ability to do so. As of now, I keep having to go into the BIOS to boot from windows 10. On the BIOS Features screen of the BIOS, i'm not even allowed to select the hard drive that has windows 10. I have to manually select the hard drive to boot from every single time. By hitting F12 on the motherboard.

If there was a way I could have the BIOS ask me which hard drive i wanted to start from everytime, that would also be nice, but I have a feeling the BIOS in this motherboard just isn't very user friendly.

Comment: B in BIOS is for "basic". Consider [GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/q/661947/693277).

Comment: What customization are you looking for exactly?  One typically allows GRUB to handle booting into Linux, but allows the Windows Bootloader, to boot into Windows.  GRUB would only be configured to point to the Bootloader.  What you are trying to achieve is not actually clear

Comment: Are you using UEFI or Legacy Boot?

Comment: Even 20+ year old bioses should allow picking a boot drive

Comment: who would vote this "off topic" here? So is the question just not a valid question? There's no legitemacy to the "off-topic" claim, this is a computer "superuser" Q&A. BIOS is not only hardware as the people who put this on hold seem to think. It's related to the manufacturers programming, this is not just a hardware question but a COMPUTER USE question in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be doing something wrong with your current board's BIOS, [it's manual](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-H170M-D3H-rev-10#support-manual) says you should be able to set the system boot order, I think using the +/-/PageUp/PageDown keys, if I'm reading the image on page 30 of section 2-4 correctly

> ### Boot Option Priorities
>
> Specifies the overall boot order from the available devices.
>
> Removable storage devices that support GPT format will be prefixed with "UEFI:" string on the boot device
>   list. To boot from an operating system that supports GPT partitioning, select the device prefixed with "UEFI:"
>   string.
>
> Or if you want to install an operating system that supports GPT partitioning such as Windows 7 64-bit, select
>   the optical drive that contains the Windows 7 64-bit installation disk and is prefixed with "UEFI:" string.
>
> ### Hard Drive/CD/DVD ROM Drive/Floppy Drive/Network Device BBS Priorities
>
> Specifies the boot order for a specific device type, such as hard drives, optical drives, floppy disk drives,
>   and devices that support Boot from LAN function, etc. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on this item to enter the submenu that
>   presents the devices of the same type that are connected. This item is present only if at least one device
>   for this type is installed.

[image: manual screenshot]

Or maybe, this setting is interfering somehow:

> ### CSM Support
>
> Enables or disables UEFI CSM (Compatibility Support Module) to support a legacy PC boot process.
>
> - Enabled - Enables UEFI CSM. (Default)
> - Disabled - Disables UEFI CSM and supports UEFI BIOS boot process only.
>
> This item is configurable only when Windows 8/10 Features is set to Windows 8/10 or Windows 8/10
>   WHQL.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, i struggle for the vocabulary to talk about what i want to do. Yes, i know you can select the boot order under "BIOS Features", but the windows drive isn't even an option under that anymore. It only shows up under the "save and exit" tab. My issue is that i want to PERMANENTLY make the windows drive the main boot drive, but im fine with manually switching to it only when i use the ubuntu drive. I've tried diddleing and researching how to do this but it doesn't appear that I can. Looks like im just going to have to go into the bios everytime which isn't terrible.